# Multiple remote EJB interfaces?

Tags: interface, ejb-3.0, stateful-session-bean

Consider the following stateful EJB (3.x):

First remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface Interface1
{
    public void setValue(int v);
}
```

Second remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface Interface2
{
    public int getValue();
}
```

Implementation of the interfaces:

```
@Stateful
public class TheEJB implements Interface1, Interface2
{
    int value = 0;

    public void setValue(int v) {value = v;}

    public int getValue() {return value;}
}
```

If I do the following in my client:

```
Interface1 interface1 = (Interface1)initialContext.lookup("***JNDI for Interface1***");
Interface2 interface2 = (Interface2)initialContext.lookup("***JNDI for Interface2***");
interface1.setValue(1);
System.out.println(interface2.getValue());
```

The output to the console will be 0 because `interface2` does not point to the same instance of the session bean as `interface1`.

So, my question is if it is possible, upon creation of `interface2` to get it to point to the same instance of the bean as `interface1` (and thus get the output 1)?

I do realise this can be achieved by putting both methods in the one interface but let's say that I want to two use two interfaces for one reason or another.

Many Thanks.